Reciving Unable to find a specification for FBReactNativeSpec depended upon by RNReanimated in a React Native Project
I am making a upgrade of the React Native version from the 0.70.6 to 0.74.3.
When I try to run the pod install inside the iOS folder. I receive this error:
[!] Unable to find a specification for `FBReactNativeSpec` depended upon by `RNReanimated`

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

npx react-native info

I already triyed with:

pod install --repo-update

and:

rm podfile.lock
pod cache clean --all
cd ios && pod install && cd ..

Any ideas ??

For everyone who encountered the same problem, update the react-native-reanimated library to the latest version (3.14.0 in my case).
Then run this command:
 pod install 

And that's it.


Remove the /ios folder
yarn add react-native-reanimated
pod install

